# How do you show which Sale a product has applied in Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce

It's easy to know if a product has a valid Sale applied to it with product.defaultVariant.onSale - but how do you know *which* Sales are being applied to the product? How do you output that the product is currently part of a specific named sale, and any associated content you might want to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real answer is:

```
{% for sale in variant.sales %}

    {% sale.description %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Luke; that's not something I could find in the docs for either the product or sale documentation pages. I tried to check again just but the Commerce site has been offline all day.

Comment: @MattWilcox I have updated the docs. Thanks.

Comment: @LukeHolder how does this work in Commerce 3, I get:

Calling unknown method: craft\commerce\elements\Variant::salesApplied()

Comment: @Green17 It would be `for sale in variant.sales`

Comment: This shows ALL sales that are applied. Some sales override previous sales, and these sales are still displayed. Is there a possibility to only see the sales that are really applied?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mike Pepper on the Slack chat, this is the answer. A bit disappointing that we need to go through hoops like this, but it works.

```
{% set productSales = [] %}
{% set allSales     = craft.commerce.getSales() %}

{% for sale in allSales if product.id in sale.productIds or product.typeId in sale.productTypeIds %}
    {% set productSales = productSales|merge([sale]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for sale in productSales if product.defaultVariant.onSale %}
    <div class="sale">
        <p><b>{{ sale.name }}</b> - {{ sale.description }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```